# XDG0062 Couldn't load type 'Ports.ViewModel.Commands.AddPortViewModel' from assembly 'Ports, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

```
<UserControl x:Class="Ports.View.AddPortView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ports.View"
             xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Ports.Model" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Ports.ViewModel.Commands"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:AddPortViewModel></vm:AddPortViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

I have been trying to bind the `AddPortViewModel` to my view, but I'm facing this error.
Yes I did just create the class and wanted to implement it but it is not working!

> XDG0062    Could not load type 'Ports.ViewModel.Commands.AddPortViewModel' from assembly 'Ports, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Could anyone know what is the reason behind it?
These are my [Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi0d2.png)

Comment: As a note, a UserControl (or any other control) should never explicitly set its own DataContext. If you do that, any standard DataContext-based Bindings of the UserControl's properties will no longer work. From an MVVM aspect, setting its own DataContext means that a control has its own "private" view model, which is disconnected from the view model structure of the application in which the control is used. DataContext should only be set for elements at the root of visual or logical trees, like Window or Page.

Comment: Um yes! I guess that is what I wanted to do. I need that mu User Control have it's own private view model which is  not related to the main window.

Comment: Are you sure that AddPortViewModel is in namespace Ports.ViewModel.Commands? Be aware that the namespace structure is not necessarily identical to the folder structure in your project.